# Error while downloading/upgrading plugins in Plugin Manager window in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to download or upgrade the plugins in JMeter Plugin manager window, the following error is displayed.

Failed to apply changes: Cannot apply changes: Have no write access for JMeter directories, not possible to use plugins manager. C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\lib\txt

Can someone tell me how to give write access to the respective file/folder?

Comment: It is interesting. Changes are applied to \lib\ext folder. You have C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\lib\txt in your error message. Can you confirm if the leaf folder is txt? If it is txt please stop Jmeter and rename it to ext.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a typo. I'm sorry. The folder is 
C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\lib\ext

Comment: You optionally copy the Plugin (jar file) to C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\lib\ext and restart the JMeter. Plugin manager does this process in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your current user doesn't have write access to `Program Files` directory, in Windows only members of [Administrators](https://kb.iu.edu/d/arnd) group can write to that folder (or you need to modify permissions for your user and [provide write access](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/) to `C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\apache-jmeter-5.2.1` folder

It should be sufficient to [run command-prompt as the administrator](https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/) and launch JMeter from that command prompt instance so it would have elevated privileges and have write access to "lib/ext", "lib" and "bin" folders of JMeter installation.

Also it is not required to have JMeter under "Program Files", you can install it to your home folder where you should have the full control.

More information: [How to Install the JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

Comment: It worked fine after running the command prompt as the administrator. Thanks for the solutions.